# How do updaters usually work? What are the steps usually taken?

Tags: http, installation

Well this is language independent even though I program in C++, but I haven't found much information about how "Auto-Updaters" work for peoples applications.

This is what I want to happen:

- User gets on my application
- Checks if Program Version is Lower than Uploaded one
- Download File and extract if its newer
- Run File
- Profit

But I don't really know how to check the Version difference, I know comparing versions is hard because you have to dig into the Version File into the Resource, and then I wouldn't know how to check the one hosted on my website.

Should I check a timestamp of the file or something? What exactly do I "compare" to see if a file should be downloaded, etc.

Comment: it doesn't have be complicated. every time you issue a new version, just increment a counter. you don't need `3.1.41.59.265`-complicated (crappy) versions, just a simple `1`, `2`, `3`, etc... then the version check is trivial. the check will just be a simple fetch of two pieces of data: "current version: X. location of installer: Y". if the installed version is smaller than `X`, you fetch `Y`

Comment: What you sketch is a security nightmare. One should _never_ download and execute code downloaded from some arbitrary website. Why should one want to do that? Expecting users to do so shows a fundamental lack of grasp on security principles...

Comment: @arkascha I was just giving a simple example of what I wanted so you guys get the picture. But for software updates where would you recommend they be hosted?

Comment: In trusted, cryptographically signed and controlled repository integrated into the local systems software management system. _And nowhere else_.

Comment: Why do you need to reinvent the wheel? There are many tools (including ours) that provide built-in support for this. More details: http://www.advancedinstaller.com/auto-updater.html